# Disabling a div's click handler with just classes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm far from an HTML wizard but do want to create a simple bootstrap button in html that I can enable and disable.  My question is, assuming this is a bootstrap button:

```
<div class="button" onClick=doSomething >My Button</div>
```

would this be the proper way to keep the same button from being clicked?

```
<div class="button disabled" onClick=doSomething >My Button</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned, you should be using button elements. If you can't for whatever reason, use [ARIA roles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role) instead for accessibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" disabled>Button</button>
```

Just switch classes `btn-primary`/`btn-secondary` and disabled state.

See documentation: [Buttons - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#disabled-state)

Answer (score 1):

You have a rather odd request here. I'm not sure why you aren't using Bootstrap classes, a button element, and the disabled attribute:

```js
function go() {
  console.log('went');
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="go()">Button</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="go()" disabled>Button</button>
```

That said, you can turn off pointer events for any element with CSS:

```js
function doSomething() {
  console.log('clicking happened');
}
```

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none; /* <-- here's your huckleberry */
  opacity: 0.65;
}

.button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onClick="doSomething()">"Button"</div>
<div class="button disabled" onClick="doSomething()">Disabled "Button"</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  btn-primary and btn-secondary did what I needed (and yes, button was kind of odd, I'm just a little lost but good now)